# Question about class member declarations

Tags: objective-c

I`m new to the Objective-C world, so I have a couple of questions about class member declarations. Please notice the comments in the code below:

In header file I have code such

```
   @interface MyClass : NSObject {

     //what we points here ? Object or something else ?
     NSString *myString;
    }
    // In interface we declare NSTring *myString in @property declaration is (NSString *) myString. 
    // What is the difference here ? Why we don`t use the same declaration as above ? 
    @property(nonatomic, retain) (NSString *) myString;
    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that instance variables (defined between curly braces) are not accessed from the outside (i.e. other objects). To do that - you have to define a property for the instance var (by using `@property` keyword) to know how outside objects can access a value of given instance var. Also in implementation file (.m) you have to `@synthesize` instance variable accessor methods for it's appropriate property. Please note that `@property` declaration not only defines what it holds (`NSString *myString`), but also **how it's being accessed and set**. You can define property as read only (`@property (readonly)...`) or accessible from few threads at a time (`@property (nonatomic)`).

Also - if your instance var is named differently from the property it represents to other objects - you must show that in implementation file (`@synthesize propertyName=instanveVariableName`)

**update**

```
MyClass *myInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myInstance myString]; // returns myString property
```

Try running above 2 lines of code without `@property` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Why we write: 
@property(nonatomic, retain) (NSString *) myString ,not 
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString; 
?

Comment: so it could be accessed from outside objects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are defining a Property of yar class.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
//public object
@public
NSString *myString;
//private object
NSString *myString2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

class structure for obj-c

.h file

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

         //Your member variable;
         // you member objects;
    }

//property declarations

//function declarations

@end
```

so it should look like

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

        NSString *str;
    }
@property(nanatomic,retain) NSString *str;

-(void)method;

@end
```